# video in webview does not work at second run

Tags: webview, xamarin.android

I have an application has a `VideosPage` page that contain a `listview` of `webviews`, each `webview` contain a video html element.
When I run the application at the first time and open `VideosPage` page, I can play, pause, open in fullscreen and close fullscreen, but when I close the application and re open it, I cannot  play, pause, open in fullscreen and close fullscreen in some device like `xiaomi pocophone f1` and `samsung galaxy a6+`, but still work good in some devices like `huawei nova 4`, `samsung j5 2016` and `huawei mate 10 lite`.
Is there a solution, an explanation?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in some devices the `webview` was not working correctly, I do not know why, but I made a work around to solve that.
I wanted a `webview` that show a video, open in full screen, play and pause.
I used `javascript` code entire my `webview` to open video by force by putting an invisible div above the play button an another invisible div above open full screen button and render the click (on my divs) events by `javascript` like that:

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
#container {width: 100%;height: 100%;position: relative;}
#navi,#navi2 {position: absolute;background-color:red;width:40px;height:40px;z-index: 10;}
#video {width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: -10;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="navi"></div>
<div id="navi2"></div>
<video id ="video" preload="none" poster="yourPoster" src="yourSource" type="video/m3u8" x-webkit-airplay="allow" style="height: 100%; position: static; visibility: visible; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;" controlsList="nodownload fullscreen" ></video>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var enabled = false;
 var con = document.getElementById('container'); 
var video =  document.getElementById('video');
 function toggleVidState(){if (video.paused) {video.play(); } else {video.pause(); }}
function toggleControls() { if (video.hasAttribute("controls")) { video.removeAttribute("controls"); enabled = false; return true; } else { video.setAttribute("controls","controls");  toggleVidState(); enabled = true;} }
video.onclick = function(){ toggleControls(); }; 
var navi = document.getElementById('navi');
 navi.onclick = function(){ if(enabled) { toggleVidState(); }};
 navi.style.left = ((con.offsetWidth/2)-20).toString() +  "px"; 
navi.style.top = ((con.offsetHeight/2)-30).toString() +  "px";
var navi2 = document.getElementById('navi2');
 navi2.onclick = function(){ video.requestFullscreen(); }; 
navi2.style.bottom = "10px"; 
navi2.style.right = "10px";
</script>
</html>
```